# Matlab can't reach Arduino UNO because serial port seems to be occupied

Tags: matlab, arduino

I'm trying to build a Matlab script that communicates with Arduino, but it says that maybe there is something else using serial port.

This is error code:

```
Failed to open serial port /dev/ttyACM0 to communicate with board Uno. Make sure there is no other MATLAB arduino object for this board. For troubleshooting, see Arduino Hardware Troubleshooting.
```

I tried everything: I started Matlab as root, rebooted over and over both my pc and Arduino, tried to change serial port's name. Also I googled this problem and found some solutions, but none worked for me. 
Any ideas?
I don't even know if there's a software output to post here.

This is my Matlab code when i open serial port.

```
Serial Port Object : Serial-/dev/ttyACM0

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               /dev/ttyACM0
      BaudRate:           9600
      Terminator:         'LF'

   Communication State 
      Status:             closed
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         0
```

PS: Serial port /dev/ttyACM0 is the right one because i found that on Arduino IDE and if I try any other port it says me 'make sure Arduino is plugged in' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with a symlink?

```
userk@dopamine:~$  sudo rm /dev/ttyS101
userk@dopamine:~$  sudo ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/ttyS101
```

Then use ttyS101 as serial port in your matlab script.
You can find a complete guide at this [link](http://userk.co.uk/matlab-arduino-serial-communication/)

Hope it helps